# Estimation problem

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

suppose we have a pdf $f(x) = \alpha x^\beta$ valid in $x \leq d$, given n iid observations, $X_1,\dots,X_n$, where $X_i \geq 0$. How do we estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from the samples?

I tried the following: Let $X_{(1)} \leq \dots \leq X_{(k)} \leq \dots \leq X_{(n)}$, where $X_{(k)}$ is the k-th order statics. We have that,

\begin{equation}
F_{X_{(i)}|X_{(n)}} (x_{(i)}|x_{(n)}) = P\left(X_{(i)} \leq x_{(n)} | X_{(n)}\leq x_n\right) = \frac{X_{(i)}^{\beta} - x_{(n)}^\beta}{x_{(n)}^\beta},
\end{equation}

then, the conditional likelihood function is given by (conditioned by $X_{(n)} \leq x_{(n)} $),
\begin{equation}
 L\left[\left\lbrace x_{(i)}\right\rbrace_{i=1}^{n-1} ; \alpha \right] = \beta^{n-1} \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{X_{(i)}^{\beta}}{x_{(n)}^{\beta}}
\end{equation}

Therefore, the $\widehat{\beta}$ is given by,

\begin{equation}
\widehat{\beta} = \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \ln \left(\frac{x_{(i)}}{x_{(n)}}\right)\right]^{-1}
\end{equation}

This is known as Hill estimator,. But still I cant find a way to estimate $\alpha$. Any ideas?

Comment: Must you have $0 \le x \le d$? If so, and $\beta\gt -1$ then $\alpha=\dfrac{\beta+1}{d^{\beta+1}}$

Comment: The minimal sufficient statistic will be $\prod X_i$ so you will presumably want to use that or its $n$th root or the logarithm of one of those as the part of the calculation of your estimator

Comment: The pdf is an asymptotic approximation, the iid observations follow the pdf $g(x)$, so $f(x) \to g(x)$ when $x \leq d$

Comment: @Henry, How can I obtain such estimator?

Comment: The [maximum likelihood estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) is not too difficult to find, especially if you differentiate the log-likelihood

Comment: Yes, but I cant find a estimator from the likelihood function the log-likelihood $\mathcal{L} = n \ln \alpha + \beta\sum X_i$ is a linear function, in dB scale. That is, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial a}$ and $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial b}$ is equal to zero rather than less than 0

Comment: correction: $\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial a^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial b^2}$

Comment: @Henry I added what I tried to do

Comment: my first comment showed the relationship between $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: I think I didn't make clear my question. But the estimator that I cite is given in: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-3/issue-5/A-Simple-General-Approach-to-Inference-About-the-Tail-of/10.1214/aos/1176343247.full